# VS Code not launching browser in ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

Here's my launch.json file. The project builds and listens correctly on the specified port, but it's not launching a browser. I'm on Mac OSX and Chrome is my default browser. What needs to be specified to launch the default browser after the project builds?

```
{
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
       {
           "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
           "type": "coreclr",
           "request": "launch", 
           "preLaunchTask": "build",
           "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/ProjectName/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/ProjectName.dll",
           "args": [],
           "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src/ProjectName",
           "stopAtEntry": false,
           "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
                "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://localhost:5001"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
            }
       },
    ]
}
```

Comment: May be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69946769/problem-using-serilog-on-net6-mvc-project-in-vs-code-on-mac

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Michelh91's answer, for serilog and debugging purposes you need to do the following 2 steps to get this working.

1. Ensure you are logging to console. You want something like this in your serilog configuration.

   "WriteTo": [
   {
   "Name": "Console",
   "Args": {
   "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
   "outputTemplate": "Some Template Format"
   }
   }
   ]

Note: the above was in my appsettings.json.

2. If you are doing any overrides of logging levels, ensure `Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime` minimum is `Information`.

Example, a common setup for overrides is something like this.

```
"Override": {
   "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "System": "Warning"        ,
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
  }
```

You need to add `"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"`, like this.

```
"Override": {
   "Microsoft": "Warning",
   "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
    "System": "Warning"        ,
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
  }
```

The reason is because VS Code is checking/scraping the console and looking for a line containing `Now listening on: https://localhost:7106` or similar.
It takes the URL from this, and launches the browser. If you override the logging levels to only warnings then this line will never be written so the browser will never launch.

Comment: In my case, someone had just added Serilog to the project.  When they configured the logger, they added the line `builder.Logging.ClearProviders();` and that prevented the "now listening on" line from showing up.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem...

Read somewhere that what VSCode does to launch the browser is to look for a "Now listening on: https://localhost:XXXX" string in the console to launch the browser.

I was using Serilog without console output, all logs where being writed to files so the console didn't had an output like that.

Disabled Serilog and launch to browser started working.

Check your console output